# Responses tab contents invisible

Tags: bug, design, meta

When you look at the "Responses" tab of your profile on the meta site, if you have new responses they are almost impossible to see:

[image: screenshot of gray on yellow text]

Can we get the color scheme for the new responses changed?

Comment: What browser is this in? I'm viewing it in Firefox 21.0/PC and it's easy to read.

Comment: Chrome v26/Windows

Comment: @SSumner The important bit the question didn't originally mention is that this only affects the Meta site, not the Main site.

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct. Sorry